# How to count the number of times each value in a tensor occurs with Tensorflow.js?

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I have a 1D tensor containing integers, for example [3,2,1,2,1,2,3,1,1,], and I wanna count how many times each integer occurs. I want the output represented with another 1D tensor, ie for the tensor above the output would be [0,4,3,2].

I know this can be done in the Python API for Tensorflow, for example using 
tf.unique_with_counts, but I haven't found a way to do this in the Tensorflow.js API.

Comment: This type of search is not what GPUs are good at so I'd advice doing this in plain JavaScript and iterating over the native TypedArray, which you can get by calling `tensor.dataSync()` or `await tensor.data()`.

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution by using tf.oneHot to create tensors with only a 1 at the index given by each element in the 1D tensor and zeros everywhere else, ie of the form [0,0,1,0] for a "2" in the 1D tensor, and then summing the output along the 0th axis.

The code is

```
    const amounts = tf.tensor1d([3,2,1,2,1,2,3,1,1,],'int32');
    const counts = tf.oneHot(amounts, 4);
    const axis = 0;
    counts.sum(axis); // Outputs [0, 4, 3, 2]
```

Answer (score 1):

A more general way, would be using a word count algorithm over the flatten tensor as demonstrated below

```
const amounts = tf.tensor1d([3.09,2,1,2,1,2,3,1,1, 3.09]);

wc =  amounts.dataSync().reduce((a, b) => a[b] ? {...a, [b]: ++a[b]} : {...a, [b]: 1}, {})
const k = tf.data.array(Object.keys(wc).map(v => ({k: v})))
const v = tf.data.array(Object.values(wc).map(v => ({v: v})))
const r = tf.data.zip([k, v]).map(x => {return {k: x[0].k, v: x[1].v}})
await r.forEach(e => console.log(JSON.stringify(e)));
```